# Adding Paginated button dynamically

Tags: javascript

I am trying to dynamically add this paginate button for the data i am getting .

But i am getting error in the console  reading paginate not defined , what can i do in such cases .

```
       function generatePaginationButtons(previous, next) {
       const pagination = document.getElementById('pagination');
       pagination.innerHTML = '';
       if (previous) {
         const prevButton = `<li class="page-item">
                               <button class="page-link" onclick="paginate('${previous}')">Previous</button>
                             </li>`;
         pagination.innerHTML += prevButton;
       }
       if (next) {
         const nextButton = `<li class="page-item">
                               <button class="page-link" onclick="paginate('${next}')">Next</button>
                             </li>`;
         pagination.innerHTML += nextButton;
       }
```

Main index.html

```
     <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
             <ul class="pagination justify-content-center"        id="pagination"></ul>
           </nav>
```

Comment: Running the provided code doesn't trigger that error. When exactly the error occurs, and on which line? Or did you mean the error message says `pagination` is not defined?

Comment: @Teemu given the code, it would occur on click on the added buttons.  OP has not provided the `function paginate() {` - or doesn't even have one, hence the error.

Comment: off topic: `paginate` = give numbers to your pages.   Clicking *next* should not then *add* numbers, it should just move to the next page that has already been paginated.

Comment: Please provide how you define the `function paginate(page) {`.   If you have it inside a `function` or `()=>` then the `onclick=` will not be able to find it.  Best option is to use proper event handlers instead of onclick= or make `function paginate() {` global.  See [mcve].

Comment: @Teemu , when i click on the Next button , it says ERROR
paginate is not defined
ReferenceError: paginate is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (http://localhost:8080/:1:1)

Comment: OK, then please edit your post as freedomn-m has adviced. Notice, that if you're going to use `addEventListener`, you will also need proper DOM handling, setting `innerHTML` recreates all the elements in the parent, and previously attached event listeners would be gone along with the old elements.